# How could Narcissa Malfoy trust Harry and take his word for it that Draco is alive?

Tags: harry-potter

Narcissa  (mother of Draco) is asked to check whether Harry is alive after he has been "killed". At this point Narcissa asks whether her son is alive. How could she trust Harry and believe him? Notwithstanding that she considered Harry to be her 'enemy'.

Harry could've have lied and said Draco was alive (if Draco was dead). In this case, Harry gets the benefit (as he escapes by being declared dead), while Narcissa is given the false hope that her son is alive. What matters isn't whether Draco is dead or alive, Harry could simply get away by saying yes.

So why did Narcissa trust Harry and take his word that Draco was alive?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot why are you removing the spaces in my question  ?

Comment: It's not correct form to have a space in these cases, see [this ELU post for example](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4646/306242).

Comment: Because the love of a mother is powerful. It's easier to think that your son is alive than to think he is dead.

Comment: @Roberto in that case why ask whether "Draco is Alive ?"

Comment: @TheMadHatter Because she needed to know. And Harry might be lying, but Narcissa still wants to believe that his son is alive.

Answer (score 7):

Narcissa is not really a Death Eater. Her loyalty goes to her family and she just followed her husband in his commitment for Voldemort.

So, she just doesn't care to tell the truth or not to Voldemort, the only thing she wants to know and to believe is whether her son is alive or not. If Harry tells her he is, she will trust him because it's just what she wants to believe. We could also assume that she doesn't want to sacrifice another life, until she is completely certain that her son is alive.

We can't assume that she trusted him beyond doubt, but she chose to trust him in the first place.

Comment: We can also assume that if she found that Harry lied, she would have killed Harry herself. She is a mother putting a desperate hope into stranger, the stranger who she believes is the only person that can stand up to Voldy and ensure her son's safety.

Comment: @jo1storm yes totally ! I thought about adding that but couldn't make a good turn of phrase. Thanks for adding.

Comment: Presumably, when one is surrounded by Death Eaters, it becomes a matter of survival to distinguish the truth from a lie. Narcissa probably could tell accurately that Harry had told the truth.